# unable to use both useFuture() and useValueChanged() in same HookWidget

Tags: flutter, flutter-hooks, graphql-flutter

I have a hook widget with `useValueChanged` listener as follows:

```
    useValueChanged(selectedLayout.value, (_, __) {
      changeLayout(selectedLayout.value);
    });
```

and `changeLayout(..)` uses `useFuture(..)` to make a graphql mutation call and return a Future wrapped inside a `AsyncSnapshot`

the value is changed in `onTap` callback as follows:

```
    onTap: () {
      selectedLayout.value = "classic";
    },
```

my HookWidget is throwing type mismatch error. any way to use `useFuture()` and `useValueChanged()` in same HookWidget?

```
Bad state: Type mismatch between hooks:
- previous hook: _ValueChangedHook<String, Null>
- new hook: _FutureHook<QueryResult>
```

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck in `useValueChanged` but I got the way to do it.
Here is the code :

```
useValueChanged(state, (_, __) {
  return controller.animateTo(
      min(controller.position.maxScrollExtent, controller.offset + 50.0),
      duration: Duration(seconds: 10),
      curve: Curves.linear);
});
```

This worked fine for me.